# Refresh Qt Creator names without reopening (automatically run parser)

Tags: c++, qt, parsing, autocomplete, qt-creator

First, sorry if my language isn't too precise, I'm only an hobbyist.

I started using Qt Creator and realized it was a nice editor with handy functionalities not included in my previous IDE (Code::Blocks).

The autocomplete and help(documentation) systems are much better then what I am used to and I find myself using them all the time. I have a small problem though:

When I modify a .h header file to add a member variable to a class, save and switch to the .cpp source to use it (always having both files open), it seems that QtCreator doesn't pick up on the new variable. The new variable isn't highlighted like the others and the autocomplete doesn't work whenever I use it.

I can close the .cpp and reopen it to update the references and make it work as intended but I figure there's a better trick. Is there an hotkey to refresh autocomplete or a way to have it update whenever I switch between files?

Comment: I had faced similar issue while using QtCreator 3 years ago. It is because, changed header is not indexed yet. Usually Re-Building my project shows new functions in auto-complete.

Answer (score 0):

What build system is that? Does it know that the .h files is part of the project? E.g. if this uses qmake, is the file listed under HEADERS += ... in the .pro file?

Comment: Yes, all the files are part of the project (listed in the .pro file). I'm not sure what you mean by build system.